# How to override get_swagger_view to enable django-rest-swagger to display all endpoints?

Tags: django, swagger-2.0, django-rest-swagger

By default `django-rest-swagger` displays my views which do not require authentication(JWT Auth in this case).
I tried to override the default `get_swagger_view` shortcut by adding `IsAuthenticated` in the permission classes to include the views which require authentication also.
But as soon as I visit the rendered docs this time, I get `No operations defined in spec!`

How do I display both the views which do and do not require authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `patch` from `unittest` module to solve the problem.

During schema generation, the request object is being checked for each view based on the list of permissions. We declare them in `permission_classes` attribute and they typically have [has_permission](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L131) method which is being called during generation. And if it raises some(`exceptions.APIException`, `Http404`, `PermissionDenied`) exceptions, generator skips that view.

If you want to patch the method of `IsAuthenticated` class you can do it this way:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

def patch_the_method(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        with patch('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated.has_permission', return_value=True):
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return inner

schema_view = patch_the_method(get_swagger_view(title='Some API'))
```

Note that this won't include views with other permissions into the schema. To avoid patching all permissions classes you can patch a method from `SchemaGenerator` class called [has_view_permissions](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d985c7cbb999b2bc18a109249c583e91f4c27aec/rest_framework/schemas/generators.py#L228).

Here is how:

```
...
with patch('rest_framework.schemas.SchemaGenerator.has_view_permissions', return_value=True):
...
```